# Remove UISlider Knob or change image swift

Tags: ios, swift, uislider

I've added a UISlider to the view. I was wondering whether it is possible to remove the knob or just change the image in swift? How can i do this?

Answer (score 10):

The slider knob is called a thumb image, and you can change it with the [setThumbImage:forState:](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISlider_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UISlider/setThumbImage:forState:) method

```
mySlider.setThumbImage(nil, forState: UIControlState.Normal) // Remove the knob image by setting it to nil, or add your own image.
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the thumb tint to clear colour from storyboard

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For Swift 5.0 or Later Version

```
for state: UIControl.State in [.normal, .selected, .application, .reserved] {
            editorSlider.setThumbImage(UIImage.init(named: "slider_thumb"), for: state)
        }
```